# Not enough space between username and rep on the questions list

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, new-nav

On the front page / new questions list, the name of the user and their reputation is too close together, and looks ugly, making it hard to read & tell apart:

[image: Screenshot]

Right now, it's `nameOfUser2,910`, it should be fixed so there's a space, eg `nameOfUser 2,910`.

With the old design (ie. before I enabled the new navigation beta) it looked right, so **this is caused by the new navigation**.

This happens on all sites and for all users who have the new navigation enabled.

Comment: No repro on Chrome 43.0.2357.81 on Windows 7.

Comment: @ryanyuyu, Strange, it looks just like in my screenshot in Chrome too.

Comment: [My screen shot](http://i.imgur.com/depbCT5.png).  I don't have that filter stuff.  Is that a stack app?

Comment: @ryanyuyu That's the new navigation, which is why you don't see it. It's a bug in the new navigation. Jonas, you should probably mention that more explicitly in your question.

Comment: @ryanyuyu, No, It's a new feature that's in beta, see the [meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256814/new-navigation-for-stack-overflow-is-in-alpha-testing) for how to enable it. That is probably why you are not seeing this.

Comment: @Kendra ah that clears up that misunderstanding.  I didn't even know that was a thing.  Maybe I should pay more attention to MSE.

Comment: [Reputation and username are now very close together!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257231/262755)

Comment: Use the question on meta.stackexchange.com that announced the navigation beta trial to post bug reports.  That's where the devs look.

Comment: @HansPassant, In that question they explicitly say adding bug reports as answers there is not encouraged. _"It's impossible to manage large amounts of bug reports or feature requests if you answer here. [...]"_

Comment: Okay, they changed that.  It isn't clear if they expect you to post to meta.stackexchange, they probably do.

Comment: @HansPassant, There's already a dupe of this on MSE. Also, there's [new-nav] tag here, so it's probably meant to be used.